# Greyed scrollbar toggles on mouse event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A greyed out scrollbar appears on my webpage whenever there is a mouse event. There are several buttons on the page and clicking them, or mouse-over/out toggles the scrollbar to appear or disappear. I don't know why. When dragging a draggable area, it toggles back and forth very fast on mouse-move. I don't see any css changes when I use the inspect element tools on Chrome.

Has anyone had this problem before or know why this may be happening?

edit:
scrollbar:
[image]

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: yes, 1 minute ..

Comment: You must have some element that is causing overflow. I would start by commenting each section one by one until I found it.

Comment: ok. i found the element. but it's height is defintely not larger than the page. what can I do ?

Comment: actually this element I found isn't causing it.

Comment: I think it is making an element width to increase, and this is making an image height increase, which makes scrollbars. still looking...

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the content will never exceed the size of the container, then you can use css to get rid of the scrollbar entirely

```
#yourContainerID {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

If you still want there to be a scrollbar when necessary, you could programatically insert one.

```
var yourContainer = document.getElementById('yourContainerID');
if (yourContainer.offsetHeight < yourContainer.scrollHeight) {
  $('#yourContainerID').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
} else {
  $('#yourContainerID').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
}
```

Comment: the page content can expand to greater than 100vh. the element causing the issue is "fixed" positioned. the only code here is changing cursor for all elements to ew-resize and that only happens on the drag area

Comment: @George Gotcha.  I've edited to include code which adds a scrollbar when needed.

Comment: thanks but it is fixed now and I didn't want a hacky fix to patch over this issue it could reduce responsiveness and may cause unexpected behaviour for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was changing 15vw padding to %. I'm still not sure why it fixed it though.

Edit:
Same issue again. I solved it a different way. I think it is to do with the body height not actually taking up the height of its contents, due to the contents perhaps being positioned relatively. I will set up a bare-bones example eventually so I can give a definitive answer to anyone else who experiences this issue.